# Block allocation in ext4 file system

Tags: ext4

Can someone explains what is defined as the "order of the request" in the buddy block allocation in ext4 file system? It was not possible to find a clear and definite answer. Is there a detailed documentation (a paper or technical report) this stuff? I read the comments in the commits but they are too short and technical. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order, as in order of magnitude, refers to the size of the allocation.